# How to change the title of input based on the input being typed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, mouseover

I've an empty input box where I can type whatever I want to. When I hover my mouse on the input it should show title as the text present in input box.

```
<input type="text" />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').mouseover(function() {
        var $txt = $('input').text();    
        $('input').attr('title', $txt);
    })
})
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/bFw2h/69/)</kbd>

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').keyup(function() {
    var $txt = $(this).val();    
    $(this).attr('title', $txt);
  })
})`

Comment: That was too quick.Didn't think of keyup. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Use `keyup` event to update the `title` attribute. As mentioned by *Alex*, Using `this` in the `handler` will read the value of the `current` input element and will update `title` attribute of the `current` input element. `$('input')` will select all the `input` tag elements and `.attr()` will set `attribute` for all the matched elements.

Also note, you should use `.val()` to get the value from the input than `text()`

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').keyup(function() {
    var $txt = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr('title', $txt);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

**Edit:** Or use [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input), *event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed.* Use `.trigger('input')` just to make sure that `title` is set `initially` before `input` event is invoked.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('input', function() {
    var $txt = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr('title', $txt);
  });
  $('input').trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value='Hello' />
```

Comment: the use of `this` seems to be more important in this case :)

Comment: Or you can use the `on('input'` event handler

Comment: also `.val()` instdead of `.text()`

Comment: What if some text is already present like `<input type="text" value="input text" />` ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `input` event to set the `title` attribute as this will catch both when people type directly in to the field, and also when they paste something in to it. Also note that to follow best practices, you should set the `title` using `prop()`, not `attr()`. Try this:

```
$('input').on('input', function() {
    $(this).prop('title', function() {
        return this.value;
    });
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/crk28nvc/)

Comment: Is there any reason why you need the anonymous function in the prop() call? Couldn't it just be: `$(this).prop('title', $(this).val());`?

Comment: It could, but it's simply a preference thing. The important part is to use `prop()`, not `attr()`

Comment: Understood. I was just looking at an edit suggestion to "clean up" the answer you posted, and while I didn't agree with the suggestion (since rejected), I personally would have written it as I posted in the comment, but wasn't sure if I was missing something and wanted to get your input.

Comment: For reference, the reason I prefer providing a function to the method is because it usually negates the need for a loop or to create another jQuery object to hold a reference to the original element. As this is a very simple case it doesn't really make much difference, but with more complex logic it's by far a better approach to use.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the input event listener:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('input',function(e) {
    var $txt = $(e.target).val();
     $(e.target).attr('title', $txt);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

to get the value from input use the `.val()`  method,

you add `.val()` value to the title attribute an you're done !!

if you have multiple `input` elements  use `$(e.target)` as  selector for getting the value and setting title attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type=text]").on("input", function() {
   $(this).attr("title", $(this).val());
});
```

you can simply use the above script, to get your requirement done.

use of `onInput` event will undertake `paste`, `drop` and other all input formats.

**Working Fiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/6pys5hoy/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script tyep="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function set_title($txt)
    {
        $('input').attr('title', $txt);
    }

   $(document).on('keyup','input',function()
   {
        var $txt = $(this).val();    
        set_title($txt);
    });

});
</script>
```

html

```
<body>
     <input type="text" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to design with JavaScript, this is what it looks like

```js
var input = document.getElementById('INPUT');
input.addEventListener('mouseup' , () => {
    input.setAttribute('title', input.value)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id='INPUT' />
```